# Why am I receiving HY093 error [PDO]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

here is my function:

```
function create($printing_id,$Machine,$Started,$Grams,$color) {
        //*
        $this->sql = "insert into `".$this->tableName."` (`3dprinting_id`,`Machine`,`Started`,`Grams`,`color`) values  ( :3dprinting_id , :Machine, :Started , :Grams , :color )";
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($this->sql);
        $this->stmt->bindParam(":3dPrinting_id",$printing_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->stmt->bindParam(":Machine",$Machine,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->stmt->bindParam(":Started",$Started,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->stmt->bindParam(":Grams",$Grams,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->stmt->bindParam(":color",$color,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->params = array();
        $this->params[":3dPrinting_id"] = $printing_id;
        $this->params[":Machine"] = $Machine;
        $this->params[":Started"] = $Started;
        $this->params[":Grams"] = $Grams;
        $this->params[":color"] = $color;
        return $this->stmt->execute();
        //*/
        /*
        $this->sql = "insert into `".$this->tableName."` (`3dprinting_id`,`Machine`,`Started`,`Grams`,`color`) values ($printing_id,'$Machine','$Started',$Grams,'$color')";
        return $this->dbh->exec($this->sql);
        //*/
    }
```

When I do it the top way (not commented out) I get an HY093 error. When I do it the bottom way it works perfectly.

In my database:

- 3dprinting_id is an int, cannot be null
- Machine is varchar(30), can be null
- Started is datetime, cannot be null
- Grams is an int, can be null
- color is varchar(30), can be null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like variables, binds are case-sensitive.

You have this in your values `( :3dprinting_id`

and then you're doing

```
bindParam(":3dPrinting_id"
```

They need to match in letter-case.

```
bindParam(":3dprinting_id"
```

Comment: Will accept this as soon as I can. I even saw this type of problem mentioned in other questions and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @cdm014 I've made that same error before and am sure many others have been there too, *cheers*